# Implement extension method interface C#

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I am newbie to C#, and have a problem with understanding how should I implement an extension method of interface. I didn't found any material about this issue. From the material I found about general extension methods in C# I expected the following simple demonstrating example work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace testExtension
{
public  interface  IcheckThingsOut
{
   bool x();
}
public static class extensionInterface
{
   public static bool y(this IcheckThingsOut bla) { return true;}
}
public class implementInteface : IcheckThingsOut
{
   bool IcheckThingsOut.x()
   {
       return true;
   }
   bool IcheckThingsOut.y()
   {
       return false;

   }
}
}
```

But the compiler is still not satisfied. What did I miss, and what is the right syntax here (with the same semantics as the code)?

Comment: What does the compiler say? Try implementing `y()` without explicitly stating the interface name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have messed up the concepts of extension methods and interfaces. Extension methods are just a compiler convenient way of calling static methods on static classes. They do not extend the interface. What the compiler does when using an extensions method is:

```
  IcheckThingsOut instance = new IcheckThingsOutImpl();
  instance.y();
```

... will be converted to:

```
  IcheckThingsOut instance = new IcheckThingsOutImpl();
  extensionInterface(instance, y);
```

So as you can see, y is not a method on your interface. This is why you can't implement it explicitly in the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

What you seem to be looking to use is "extension methods". Your `extensionInterface` class is properly implemented for this purpose.

However, creating an extension method does not actually extend your interface, so although you can call `myIcheckThingsOut.y()`, you cannot re-implement the method in a class that implements `IcheckThingsOut`, implicitly or explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can not change the implementation of an extension method inside the "extended" class or interface. The extension method IS the implementation.

Extension methods provide a way to "add" methods to an interface or a class. The whole idea is that the interface or class you are extending does not "know" about these methods. In other words, you "add" functionality without altering the class or interface itself.

(Note that while the notation suggests that your are adding methods to the interface, in fact these methods are plain static methods as far as the runtime is concerned).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool IcheckThingsOut.y()
{
    return false;

}
```

is wrong: IcheckThingsOut provides no prototype for function `y`. It should just be

```
bool y()
{
    return false;
}
```

since it's just shadowing the other method

Answer (score 0):

The IcheckThingsOut dosn't have bool y()